# Flutter not able to navigate to another screen on google Sign in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

> I have made a login Screen where I am logging in using google from firebase. Logging in is working fine as I am able to access uid and post data on firebase but I am not able to navigate to homescreen on tapping the login button.It just logs in using google and stays in the login screen.

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
   GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    // Step 2
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
   final AuthCredential cred= GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
   FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(cred)).user;
   return user;
}  




onTap:() async { 
                     await _auth.signInWithGoogle();
                     Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homescreen');
                      },
```

> Above are my `GoogleAuth` function and `onTap` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better don't use `async` in `onTap()` function.
Define another function and do something like this.

```
void handleLogin() async {
   FirebaseUser user = await signInWithGoogle();
   // Here signInWithGoogle() is your defined function!
   if(user != null){
       Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homescreen');
   }else{
      // Something Wrong!
   }
}
```

Call this new function on your `onTap()`

```
onTap: () {
    handleLogin();
}
```

> Note that you don't have `async` in `onTap()`
> Try it, this may solve your issue.

Comment: Its working only when i remove that if user! null statement though,Thanks for the help.

Comment: If so, the user has not logged in successfully!
`user != null` should be true if the user logged in successfully!

Comment: but after navigating into homescreen I am able to post data using user uid in firebase.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the cache. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. I may then seem good.